# How to use AzureAd for only an Area (Admin) and regular Identity for root (User) in .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, .net-5

I need to Authenticate users by different schemes for different Areas in my .net 5 mvc app. Here is the boiler plate code for AzureAD template;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name : "areas",
                pattern : "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
```

I need to use AzureAD for Admin area and Identity (auth with a DB server basically) for the root area, how do I do that, is it even possible? (without manual labor)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using MSAL only on admin side and [Identity framework](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-or-Microsoft.Identity.Web) for non-admin users.

You can configure the MSAL in your .NET core application. Learn more [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet).

In your Startup.cs class you need to update configure method meaning you need to setup the middleware for authentication.

Learn more about MSAL+ Microsoft.Identity.Web [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7_Fj1zFLO0).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reading most of the documentation you've linked, I couldn't find how to map an Auth mechanism to a specific area of the app?

Comment: To map an Auth mechanism to a specific area to the app start with this doc.
https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg

After following the above doc implement the MSAL in your application. You need to follow every step to implement MSAL in .net core.
Then by following this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio you will implement the Identity framework in your application for non-admin users.

Remember to use jwt.